# Attributes grid in Magento

Tags: magento

Product is a car part. This car part is available for several car models, years and engines.
Eg:

```
Product: Oil Filter
Valid for:
VW Yetta  2015  diesel
VW Yetta  2015  fuel
VW Yetta  2014  diesel
VW Beatle 2015  diesel
VW Beatle 2015  fuel
...
```

I don't need for each combination to be a simple product. Just for the values to be selectable in the admin and output a grid in the frontend. Also values need to be filter-friendly to some degree (at least saved separately in the DB).

Is there a way to do this without manual coding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this commercial plugin in the same way:
https://amasty.com/product-parts-finder.html

You can purchase this Or you can take idea from this if you want to develop your own.

Comment: Thanks! Exaclty what I needed. I'll test it out.